# Telosb with GPS

Tags: networking, gps, sensors, wireless

i am currently working with my thesis, my thesis is all about measuring ocean current through the use of a Wireless Sensor Network Mote, specifically i will be using Crossbow's TelosB. 
How can you interface a GPS module with Telosb? what GPS module is compatible with TelosB?

Comment: This is too general, you should have done some research so that you could have asked more sensible question. Edit your question to be specific one.

Comment: what specific do you want? that's why i am asking it here. because i do not know what GPS module is compatible with Telosb (WSN mote)

Comment: kindly edit your question or rephrase it, so that I can remove the down-vote from your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All GPS modules support the NMEA protocol, so a system that should work with different GPS chips, will use that NMEA protocoll.
Additionaly GPS modules support their own binary protocoll, but by default the NMEA protocoll is enabaled.

Systems that reads from a GPS module, usually allow to configure the (COM) port and the baud rate where the GPS is connected.

Chances are high that after setting these two params the system succesfully reads location data from the GPS chip.

Answer (score 1):

SIMCOM,QUECTEL,TELIT and NEOWAY provides one of the most reliable GPS. Hace a look into their official products page you will meet your requirements.